# Selected row insert to database

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I want to insert a data from selected data from datagridview.

This is my code

```
using (var connection = HelperLayer.GetConnection())
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        string sqll = @"insert into SmsTableInvoice(code, telno, ficheno, TRCode, netTotal,message) 
                        values('"+code+"','"+telno+ "','"+ ficheno+ "','"+ trcode+ "','"+ total + "','"+ConvertStringArrayToString(sms)+ "') ";
         
        var command = new SqlCommand(sqll, connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Control();
     
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This code add all data
How to add just selected row
Thank you for everyone

Comment: How did you fill the DGV?  Are you using a DataAdapter to fill a DataTable?  The row number of the DataTable and the DGV are the same.  so you can write data from DataTable instead of DGV.

Answer (score 0):

save button action: 
if one data: var index = dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index;
code = dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["code"].Value.ToString(); ....
if > one data: for(int i=0;i<dataGridViewAddMX.RowCount;i++) { 
if EditedFormattedValue == true { 
code = dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["code"].Value.ToString(); .... }}